# Laravel seed table from multiple csv files

Tags: sql, database, laravel-5, database-migration

I'm very new to Laravel and Database and I'm trying to understand how to insert data into my database. Please be patient the question can sounds dummy for you.

1. STEP

I created a table in migrations. Example of a table:

```
public function up(){

        Schema::create('job-urls', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->foreign('job_id')->references('id')->on('jobs');
            $table->string('url')->index();
            $table->string('hash');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
```

2. STEP

I have two csv file that correspond to the field `url` and `hash` and I want to insert them. I created a new file in migration called `populate_jobs_url`

```
class PopulateJoburls extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up(){
        $fileurls = fopen('../data/urls.csv', 'r');
        $filehash = fopen('../data/urls_hash.csv', 'r');

        while (($row = fgetcsv($fileurls, 0, ',')) !=FALSE){
            DB::table('joburls')->insert(
                array(
                    'url' => $row,
                )
            );
        }
        while (($row = fgetcsv($filehash, 0, ',')) !=FALSE){
            DB::table('joburls')->insert(
                array(
                    'hash' => $row,
                )
            );
        }
    }
```

Can you help me to understand how I check if the table is correctly filled? Is this approach correct? How could I insert data otherwise in my Database? Unfortunately all examples on the web deal with inserting manually data with a form.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seeding the table inside of a migration file is not the best practise. You can take advantage of [Seeders](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/seeding), which is right way to fill your table with test or actual data.

First, create a seeder file with `php artisan make:seeder PopulateJobUrls` command. Then you can arrange your seeder like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class PopulateJobUrls extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
     public function run()
     {
         $fileurls = fopen('../data/urls.csv', 'r');
         $filehash = fopen('../data/urls_hash.csv', 'r');

         // Rest of your seeding logic...
     }
}
```

You should reference your seeder from `database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php` in the run method:

```
$this->call(PopulateJobUrls::class);
```

Run `php artisan db:seed` or if you want to be more specific, `php artisan db:seed --class=PopulateJobUrls` and you are good to go with your correctly filled data!

Comment: In [this discrussion](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/populate-database-in-laravel) I learned that seeder is not the best way to populate a database. I'm very confused.